# When is a linear operator the gradient of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, multivariable-calculus, operator-theory, convex-analysis

Let $F(x) = Ax$, where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Under what condition does there exist a $f$, such that $\nabla f = F$?

It is clear to me this happens when $A$ is diagonal matrix. Is there any other conditions on the matrix $A$ such that $f$ exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Claim:** If $A$ is symmetric, then such an $f$ exists.

*Proof:* Let $A$ be symmetric. Take $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx$. Then

$$
(\nabla f(x))_k = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \frac{1}{2}\sum_i \sum_j A_{ij}x_ix_j = \sum_i \sum_j \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}(x_ix_j) A_{ij}
$$

We have $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}(x_ix_j) = 2x_i$ if $i=j=k$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}(x_ix_j) = x_j$ if $i = k$ and $j \ne k$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}(x_ix_j) = x_i$ if $i \ne k$ and $j = k$. If $i \ne k$ and $j \ne k$ then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}(x_ix_j) = 0$.

We're good when $i=k$ since we have a factor of 2 to cancel out the $1/2$. Notice that for each $i \ne k$, the term $A_{ik}x_ix_k$ and $A_{ki}x_kx_i$ both appear in the sum. Under assumption of symmetry, these terms are equal, which gives us the factor of 2 needed to cancel out the $1/2$.

Thus through the computations yields

$$
(\nabla f(x))_k = \sum_i A_{ki} x_i = (Ax)_k
$$

In other words, $\nabla f = F$.